# What are the best (portable) cross-platform arbitrary-precision math libraries?

Tags: c++, c, biginteger, bigdecimal, gmp

I’m looking for a good arbitrary precision math library in C or C++. Could you please give me some advices or suggestions?

The primary requirements:

1. It **must** handle arbitrarily big integers—my primary interest is on integers. In case that you don’t know what the word arbitrarily big means, imagine something like 100000! (the factorial of 100000).
2. The precision **must not need** to be specified during library initialization or object creation. The precision should **only** be constrained by the available resources of the system.
3. It **should** utilize the full power of the platform, and should handle “small” numbers natively. That means on a 64-bit platform, calculating (2^33 + 2^32) should use the available 64-bit CPU instructions. The library **should not** calculate this in the same way as it does with (2^66 + 2^65) on the same platform.
4. It **must** efficiently handle addition (`+`), subtraction (`-`), multiplication (`*`), integer division (`/`), remainder (`%`), power (`**`), increment (`++`), decrement (`--`), GCD, factorial, and other common integer arithmetic calculations. The ability to handle functions like square root and logarithm that do not produce integer results is a plus. The ability to handle [symbolic computations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation) is even better.

Here are what I found so far:

1. **Java**'s **[BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)** and **[BigDecimal](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)** class: I have been using these so far. I have read the source code, but I don’t understand the math underneath. It may be based on theories and algorithms that I have never learnt.
2. The built-in integer type or in core libraries of **[bc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html)**, **[Python](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals)**, **Ruby**, **Haskell**, **Lisp**, **Erlang**, **OCaml**, **PHP**, some other languages: I have used some of these, but I have no idea which library they are using, or which kind of implementation they are using.

What I have already known:

1. Using `char` for decimal digits and `char*` for decimal strings, and do calculations on the digits using a `for`-loop.
2. Using `int` (or `long int`, or `long long`) as a basic “unit” and an array of that type as an arbitrary long integer, and do calculations on the elements using a `for`-loop.
3. Using an integer type to store a decimal digit (or a few digits) as **[BCD (Binary-coded decimal)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)**.
4. **[Booth’s multiplication algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm)**.

What I don’t know:

1. Printing the binary array mentioned above in decimal without using naive methods. An example of a naive method: (1) add the bits from the lowest to the highest: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, … (2) use a `char*`-string mentioned above to store the intermediate decimal results).

What I appreciate:

1. Good comparisons on **[GMP](http://gmplib.org/)**, **[MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/)**, **[decNumber](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decnumber.html)** (or other libraries that are good in your opinion).
2. Good suggestions on books and articles that I should read. For example, an illustration with figures on how a **non-naive** binary-to-decimal conversion algorithm works would be good. The article “**[Binary to Decimal Conversion in Limited Precision](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/%7Ejones/bcd/decimal.html)**” by Douglas W. Jones is an example of a good article.
3. Any help in general.

Please **do not** answer this question if you think that using `double` (or `long double`, or `long long double`) can solve this problem easily. If you do think so, you don’t understand the issue in question.

Comment: As far as I can see, GMP seems to be a good library. What I wonder is why there's a need for the contributors of Python / Haskell / Erlang / etc to re-invent the wheel. If GMP is so good, why don't rely on it? The GPL / LGPL license may be one of the issues, but despite of this (and also the rounding mode issue), are there any other disadvantages of GMP? Is the built-in integer of Python / Haskell / Erlang / any cryptography library faster than GMP? If so, I would like to extract and use it, if license permits.

Comment: I found a nice article at http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/decimal.html by Douglas W. Jones. The article describes a method to convert a 16-bit integer to decimal representation using only 8-bit integer arithmetic. The idea is to break the 16-bit number into 4 nibbles, each representing a base-16 "digit". So, digit-0 (n0) represents x1, n1 => x16, n2 => x256, n3 => x4096. Then, it is obvious that digit-0 of the decimal number (d0) is digit-0 of the result of n0 * 1 + n1 * 6 + n2 * 6 + n3 * 6. By handling the carry properly, d1 to d4 can also be computed.

Comment: However, as far as I could imagine, Douglas's idea above could not be extended to handle arbitrarily long binary integers. It is because the numbers 1 (16^0), 16 (16^1), 256 (16^2) and 4096 (16^3) are pre-calculated. The problem then becomes how to represent 16^n in decimal for arbitrarily large n.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

GMP is the popular choice.  Squeak Smalltalk has a very nice library, but it's written in Smalltalk.

You asked for relevant books or articles.  The tricky part of bignums is long division.  I recommend Per Brinch Hansen's paper [Multiple-Length Division Revisited: A Tour of the Minefield](http://www.brinch-hansen.net/papers/1994b.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your link to the paper! Yes, I agree that division is the most tricky part. I knew how to do division by hand using "paper-and-pencil methods" long time ago :-), and thus the same method can be applied to a decimal string of `char *` (each `char` representing a decimal digit) or an `int *` of BCD string (each `int` representing 4 / 8 / 16 BCD digits). However, I wonder if real-world production level libraries mimics the "paper-and-pencil method", as it is too slow.

Comment: To see why, let's imagine how it runs for `100,000,000,000,000,000 / 333,333,333,333`: The first step is to compare `100,000,000,000` with `333,333,333,333`. Because the former is less than the latter, the calculation simply moves to the next digit. The second step is to find the quotient of `1,000,000,000,000 / 333,333,333,333`, this involves either a trial-and-error multiplication of `333,333,333,333 * 1` (and `* 2`, `* 3` and `* 4`), or doing successive subtractions in a loop. Do you see how slow it is? I believe that more efficient algorithms exist.

Comment: @Sui: Brinch Hanson shows how you can reduce the trial-and-error method to at most two trials.  It's really very impressive.

Comment: Okay, let me have a more detailed look to the paper. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure where you ended up finding your solution, nor what format you used to store digits, but COBOL's COMP-3 nybble format is a lot nicer to deal with, as it's more compact, each 4 bits storing a 0-9 value, AND, you aren't required to subtract hex 30 from the ASCII char value to get a usable digit.

Answer (score 15):

Overall, he fastest general purpose arbitrary precision library is [GMP](http://gmplib.org/). If you want to work with floating point values, look at the the [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) library. MPFR is based on GMP.

Regarding native arbitrary precision support in other languages, Python uses its own implementation because of license, code size, and code portability reasons. The [GMPY](http:///code.google.com/p/gmpy/) module lets Python access the GMP library.

Comment: Thank you for your response! You mentioned "code portability". Could you please explain what the problem is? I thought that GMP is portable and is supported on major platforms...

Comment: "code portability" is not the same as "supported on major platforms". Python uses a simple implementation that makes very few assumptions about the behavior of the C compiler so the same code can compile on almost any C compiler. GMP uses more code (C and highly-tuned assembly) that make GMP faster but also make more assumptions about the behavior of the C compiler and assembler. For example, GMP is not well supported by the Microsoft Visual Studio compilers. There is a GMP fork called MPIR (www.mpir.org) that does support Microsoft's compilers.

Comment: I see. That means the Python implementation is more like ANSI C while the GMP implementation uses __asm tricks... Thank you for your explanations.

Answer (score 13):

See [TTMath](http://ttmath.org), a small templated header-only library free for personal and commercial use.

Comment: Hey! This is a easy-to-use library, and it seems it utilizes the CPU power and it uses some C++ template magic to complete the job. Great library! +1 for you!

Comment: Yeah, and it has a permissive non-copyleft BSD license.

Comment: From the page above: "How big the values can be is set at compile time." - so this does not fit the requirements.

Answer (score 9):

I've not compared arbitrary precision arithmetic libraries to each other myself, but people who do seem to have more or less uniformly settled on GMP. For what it's worth, the arbitrary precision integers in GHC Haskell and GNU Guile Scheme are both implemented using GMP, and the fastest implementation of the [pidigits benchmark on the language shootout](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/program.php?test=pidigits&lang=gcc&id=4) is based on GMP.

Comment: Thanks! ^___^ Nice information!

Answer (score 5):

What about [Pari](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)? It’s built on top GMP and provides all the other goodies about number theory operations you’ll ever need (and many symbolic computation stuff).

Comment: You are welcome :-) Also with Pari you can roll fast prototypes using GP and when you're happy write the optimised C version (and I think it comes with a GP->C compiler to help with that too)