# What's the best (for speed) arbitrary-precision library for C++?

Tags: c++, c, precision, arbitrary-precision

I need the fastest library that is available for C++. My platform will be x86 and x86-64 which supports floating points.

Comment: I know there is a duplicate of this somewhere

Comment: @Earlz: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568446/the-best-cross-platform-portable-arbitrary-precision-math-library

Comment: It should be pointed out that two questions have been asked here with conflicting requirements.  Best is not necessarily fastest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[GMPLIB](http://gmplib.org/)

GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed ... C++ class based interface to all of the above.

Comment: GMP is a very bad choice if you care about robustness. It will `abort` the calling program if it runs out of memory, which can easily happen if you're not paranoid about controlling the magnitude of numbers you pass to it.

Comment: You should mention if your system has floating point hardware or not.  Most do now, some of my platforms do not.

Comment: My platform would be x86-64 and x86, which should have floating point support. I just need one to calculate Pi with the Chudnovsky algorithm, or other mathematical constants such as e, as fast as possible.

Comment: Can you tell us why? On a home system even with the fastest algorithms, it will still take some time to calculate pi to the number of already-known digits.

Comment: It takes MaxxPi2 1 second to calculate 1024^2 digits. I want to create something similar; it's for use as a benchmark.

Comment: @Victor: that would be a remarkably poor benchmark from which to draw any meaningful conclusions.