# fast arbitrary precision c++ library: is __float128 faster than MPFR?

Tags: c++, gmp, bignum, arbitrary-precision, mpfr

I know there are a couple of thread on similar topics ( [What's the best (for speed) arbitrary-precision library for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486882/whats-the-best-for-speed-arbitrary-precision-library-for-c) and [The best cross platform (portable) arbitrary precision math library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568446/the-best-cross-platform-portable-arbitrary-precision-math-library) ) and I take from these threads than GMP or something based on it like MPFR is the fastest lib available, but I am specifically wondering: if I only wanted say 30 dec places would __float128 of the quadmath lib be faster?

Also how does MAPM stack up against MPFR?

It looks from this website:

http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/benchs/timings-mpfr.html

that MPFR does pretty well, but there are also CLN and apfloat?

Comment: As a side note (you probably are aware of this, but just to be sure), a quad-precision float doesn't give you ~30 decimal places but 113 binary places.

Comment: I know quad is 120bits in total, but I thought that equated roughly to 30deci?

Comment: You're of course right (though, it's 128 bits in total). I just wanted you to keep in mind that binary floating point numbers don't give you actual decimal precision. It's very likely you already know this, but just to be sure. So don't expect your exact decimal number with 30 places to be represented **exactly** in binary quad-precision, they will only *equate roughly* to each other.

Comment: A double-double library might be the fastest (a bit less precision than float128, but uses the FPU), unless you have hardware float128 (some IBM computers I think). But if you need many weird functions, availability is likely the only criterion you can afford.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want 30 decimal places, I'm pretty sure (without actually benchmarking it), that GMP or MPFR can not be as fast as some simple home-brewn routines.  That depends a bit on the operations you need, of course.

The reason behind this is that GMP et al. are really well-written with very large integers in mind (like 1,000+ or even 1,000,000+ decimal digits).  But for very small -- yet too big for int -- bignums, the overhead of some extra if's, calls or even memory allocation will kill them in every benchmark.

It's an easy exercise to build your own C++ functions that give you 128 bits addition/subtraction from 2 64 bit unsigned's.  Even multiplication is done easily.  Division might not be as simple, but do you need that?  More elaborate functions (roots, log, etc) are much more work and then GMP et al. will maybe pay off.

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately I do need the elaborate functions.

Comment: What exactly do you need? And in which precision?

Comment: 50-60dp of precision and just about everything from log, abs, pow, roots and more.

Comment: As long as the results are again integers, square and cube roots, logarithm and integer powers are not too difficult.  See "Hacker's delight" by H S Warren for details.

Comment: The question is about MPFR and __float128. Why is this answer about integers and integer operations?

Comment: Because any float calculation can well be accomplished with integer arithmetic as well. He knows the precision he needs, that makes it easier to use integers.

Comment: @cxxl Hoping you can help me. I need to represent 20-24 digits exactly. The only operations I need are add, subtract, multiply, divide, abs, min and max. Could you recommend what my best approach would be? As you said, GMP etc are too slow for usage just-beyond 64 bits.  Boost multiprecision seems to be about 300 cycles per operation, I was hoping for maybe 50-100 cycles. Could I copy the C# Decimal class to suit my needs and get the precision and performance I require?

Comment: What do you mean by 'exactly'? That can be very tricky. Does `1/3*3 == 1` hold? If so, use rationals. Does `0.1+0.1+...` (10 times) `== 1.0`? If so, use something like Python Decimals (in your language of choice). Do you want operations with guaranteed error bounds? Then GNU MPFR might be a good choice. If it's not super-super important, you can use floats and round after the operations.