# numeric values bigger than ULLONG_MAX

Tags: c, performance, integer-arithmetic

I need to store and use numeric values bigger than `ULLONG_MAX`.

I will need to make arithmetic operations with those values, so I think store as `char**` is not a option.

Is there a way to dynamically create an additional `long` prefix in those cases?

---

Thank you all. Based on responses, Very helpful but I doubt about the best performance option. piokuc quote a performance link, but it's unclear. In this time I'm between GMP or MPIR, there is some one faster?

Comment: See e.g. http://gmplib.org/

Comment: You seem obsessed with performance. *Make it right before you make it fast.* And note that a `long double` can be *way* larger than unsigned long longs.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use one of the arbitrary precision arithmetic libraries, like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), see also  [What's the best (for speed) arbitrary-precision library for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486882/whats-the-best-for-speed-arbitrary-precision-library-for-c)

Comment: I don't think it can ben a new post, but.. The link about performance seems ineffective, there is no benchmark reference to say that GMP is the better... seems a filling, what about MPIR, it's a fork with GPU intents, what's the better for a new software ? GMP or MPIR?

Comment: I didn't know MPIR. It seems to be a lively project with a momentum, there is a community of users and contributors behind it, which is great. Apparently they added a lot of stuff on top of GMP. It depends on your requirements and set up, for examples if you are on Linux then I guess you have GMP already installed and so it will be easier for you to start with it. On the other hand I presume the basic API for arbitrary precision maths should be the same or very similar in both libs so it should be easy to switch from one to the other if you start with the common subset.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to multi-precision libraries such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org), if you are using GCC on a 64-bit architecture, you also have the option of using `__int128` ([documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html)).

Comment: clang also supports `__int128_t` (and `__uint128_t`).

Comment: The code won't be portable in any way, but if you only need a quick and dirty job - then this is great

Comment: dirty, understood, but what about performance? is (__uint128 or __uint128_t) better than GMP ?

Comment: @ton I wouldn't say it “dirty” (that was cluracan's comment). It fills a different niche. It is much faster if you only need 128 bits. GMP spends its time loading lengths from dynamically allocated objects and looping unknown numbers of iterations (varying according to operands' lengths). 128-bit operations are straight executions paths, 2 64-bit additions to simulate one 128-bit addition, 4 multiplications to simulate one 128-bit multiplication, this kind of thing. Don't get me wrong, GMP is well-written and optimized, but you can't expect it to fight against __int128 on its own ground