# How to use negative number with openssl's BIGNUM?

Tags: c++, openssl, bignum

I want a C++ version of the following Java code.

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("00afd72b5835ad22ea5d68279ffac0b6527c1ab0fb31f1e646f728d75cbd3ae65d", 16);
BigInteger y = x.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(-1));

//prints y = ff5028d4a7ca52dd15a297d860053f49ad83e54f04ce0e19b908d728a342c519a3
System.out.println("y = " + new String(Hex.encode(y.toByteArray())));
```

And here is my attempt at a solution.

```
BIGNUM* x = BN_new();
BN_CTX* ctx = BN_CTX_new();
std::vector<unsigned char> xBytes = hexStringToBytes(“00afd72b5835ad22ea5d68279ffac0b6527c1ab0fb31f1e646f728d75cbd3ae65d");
BN_bin2bn(&xBytes[0], xBytes.size(), x);

BIGNUM* negative1 = BN_new();
std::vector<unsigned char> negative1Bytes = hexStringToBytes("ff");
BN_bin2bn(&negative1Bytes[0], negative1Bytes.size(), negative1);

BIGNUM* y = BN_new();
BN_mul(y, x, negative1, ctx);

char* yHex = BN_bn2hex(y);
std::string yStr(yHex);
//prints y = AF27542CDD7775C7730ABF785AC5F59C299E964A36BFF460B031AE85607DAB76A3
std::cout <<"y = " << yStr << std::endl;
```

(Ignored the case.) What am I doing wrong? How do I get my C++ code to output the correct value "ff5028d4a7ca52dd15a297d860053f49ad83e54f04ce0e19b908d728a342c519a3". I also tried setting negative1 by doing BN_set_word(negative1, -1), but that gives me the wrong answer too.

Comment: You have a weird quote mark in `hexStringToBytes(“00`  ... hopefully that is a copy-paste error rather than actually in your source file

Comment: have you tried `BN_set_negative` ?

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't seem to work either. would just get "-AFD72B5835AD22EA5D68279FFAC0B6527C1AB0FB31F1E646F728D75CBD3AE65D"

Comment: well the negative of afd... *is* -afd...

Comment: Maybe add the tag "java" - I am understanding your requirements by reading online documentation for BigInteger; possibly I have misread the documentation someone more experienced in Java may be able to clarify

Comment: Note that `BN_bin2bn` only reads positive numbers ; your second paragraph of sample code here would generate the positive integer `255`.

Comment: Man, I can't believe you burned 100 points on that question.... Here's a charity +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BN_set_negative` function sets a negative number.

The negative of `afd72b5835ad22ea5d68279ffac0b6527c1ab0fb31f1e646f728d75cbd3ae65d` is actually `-afd72b5835ad22ea5d68279ffac0b6527c1ab0fb31f1e646f728d75cbd3ae65d` , in the same way as `-2` is the negative of `2`.

`ff5028d4a7ca52dd15a297d860053f49ad83e54f04ce0e19b908d728a342c519a3` is a large positive number.

The reason you are seeing this number in Java is due to the `toByteArray` call . [According to its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray()), it selects the minimum field width which is a whole number of bytes, and also capable of holding a two's complement representation of the negative number.

In other words, by using the `toByteArray` function on a number that current has 1 sign bit and 256 value bits, you end up with a field width of 264 bits.  However if your negative number's first nibble were `7` for example, rather than `a`, then (according to this documentation - I haven't actually tried it) you would get a 256-bit field width out (i.e. `8028d4...`, not `ff8028d4`.

The leading `00` you have used in your code is insignificant in OpenSSL BN. I'm not sure if it is significant in BigInteger although the documentation for that constructor says "The String representation consists of an optional minus or plus sign followed by a sequence of one or more digits in the specified radix. "; so the fact that it accepts a minus sign suggests that if the minus sign is not present then the input is treated as a large positive number, even if its MSB is set. (Hopefully a Java programmer can clear this paragraph up for me).

Make sure you keep clear in your mind the distinction between a *large negative value*, and a large positive number obtained by modular arithmetic on that negative value, such as is the output of `toByteArray`.

---

So your question is really: does Openssl BN have a function that emulates the behaviour of BigInteger.toByteArray() ?

I don't know if such a function exists (the BN library has fairly bad documentation IMHO, and I've never heard of it being used outside of OpenSSL, especially not in a C++ program). I would expect it doesn't, since `toByteArray`'s behaviour is kind of weird; and in any case, all of the BN output functions appear to output using a sign-magnitude format, rather than a two's complement format.

But to replicate that output, you could add either `2^256` or `2^264` to the large negative number , and then do `BN_bn2hex` . In this particular case, add `2^264`, In general you would have to measure the current bit-length of the number being stored and round the exponent up to the nearest multiple of 8.

Or you could even output in sign-magnitude format (using `BN_bn2hex` or `BN_bn2mpi`) and then iterate through inverting each nibble and fixing up the start!

NB. Is there any particular reason you want to use OpenSSL BN? [There are many alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568446/the-best-cross-platform-portable-arbitrary-precision-math-library).

Comment: BN_bn2mpi outputs in sign-magnitude format (it just sets up the start and then calls BN_bn2bin)

Comment: THe docs are terrible, I had to look in the source code to find out what actually happens

Answer (score 2):

Although this is a question from 2014 (more than five years ago), I would like to solve your problem / clarify the situation, which might help others.

### a) One's complement and two's complement

In finite number theory, there is "one's complement" and "two's complement" representation of numbers. One's complement stores absolute (positive) values only and does not *know* a sign. If you want to have a sign for a number stored as one's complement, then you have to store it separately, e.g. in one bit (0=positive, 1=negative). This is exactly the situation of floating point numbers (IEEE 754). The mantissa is stored as the one's complement together with the exponent and one additional sign bit. Numbers in one's complement have two zeros: -0 and +0 because you treat the sign independently of the absolute value itself.

In two's complement, the most significant bit is used as the sign bit. There is no '-0' because negating a value in two's complement means performing the logical NOT (in C: tilde) operation followed by adding one.
As an example, one byte (in two's complement) can be one of the three values 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01 meaning -1, 0 and 1. There is *no room* for the -0. If you have, e.g. 0xFF (-1) and want to negate it, then the logical NOT operation computes 0xFF => 0x00. Adding one yields 0x01, which is 1.

### b) OpenSSL BIGNUM and Java BigInteger

OpenSSL's BIGNUM implementation represents numbers as one's complement. The Java BigInteger treats numbers as two's complement. That was your desaster. Your big integer (in hex) is 00afd72b5835ad22ea5d68279ffac0b6527c1ab0fb31f1e646f728d75cbd3ae65d. This is a positive 256bit integer. It consists of 33 bytes because there is a leading zero byte 0x00, which is absolutely correct for an integer stored as two's complement because the most significant bit (omitting the initial 0x00) is set (in 0xAF), which would make this number a negative number.

### c) Solution you were looking for

OpenSSL's function bin2bn works with absolute values only. For OpenSSL, you can leave the initial zero byte or cut it off - does not make any difference because OpenSSL canonicalizes the input data anyway, which means cutting off all leading zero bytes. The next problem of your code is the way you want to make this integer negative: You want to multiply it with -1. Using 0xFF as the only input byte to bin2bn makes this 255, not -1. In fact, you multiply your big integer with 255 yielding the overall result AF27542CDD7775C7730ABF785AC5F59C299E964A36BFF460B031AE85607DAB76A3, which is still positive.

Multiplication with -1 works like this (snippet, no error checking):

```
BIGNUM* x = BN_bin2bn(&xBytes[0], (int)xBytes.size(), NULL);
BIGNUM* negative1 = BN_new();
BN_one(negative1); /* negative1 is +1 */
BN_set_negative(negative1, 1); /* negative1 is now -1 */
BN_CTX* ctx = BN_CTX_new();
BIGNUM* y = BN_new();
BN_mul(y, x, negative1, ctx);
```

Easier is:

```
BIGNUM* x = BN_bin2bn(&xBytes[0], (int)xBytes.size(), NULL);
BN_set_negative(x,1);
```

This does not solve your problem because as M.M said, this just makes -afd72b5835ad22ea5d68279ffac0b6527c1ab0fb31f1e646f728d75cbd3ae65d from afd72b5835ad22ea5d68279ffac0b6527c1ab0fb31f1e646f728d75cbd3ae65d.

You are looking for the two's compülement of your big integer, which is

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(value); i++)
  value[i] = ~value[i];

for (i = ((int)sizeof(posvalue)) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  value[i]++;
  if (0x00 != value[i])
    break;
}
```

This is an unoptimized version of the two's complement if 'value' is your 33 byte input array containing your big integer prefixed by the byte 0x00. The result of this operation are the 33 bytes ff5028d4a7ca52dd15a297d860053f49ad83e54f04ce0e19b908d728a342c519a3.

### d) Working with two's complement and OpenSSL BIGNUM

The whole sequence is like this:

1. Prologue: If input is negative (check most significant bit), then compute two's complement of input.
2. Convert to BIGNUM using BN_bin2bn
3. If input was negative, then call BN_set_negative(x,1)
4. Main function: **Carry out all arithmetic operations using OpenSSL BIGNUM package**
5. Call BN_is_negative to check for negative result
6. Convert to raw binary byte using BN_bn2bin
7. If result was negative, then compute two's complement of result.
8. Epilogue: If result was positive and result raw (output of step 7) byte's most significant bit is set, then prepend a byte 0x00. If result was negative and result raw byte's most significant bit is clear, then prepend a byte 0xFF.