# Which data type can hold 10^31 decimal number?

Tags: c++, variables, range

I have to keep **10^31** range decimal data in an integer data type variable.

Which data type can hold this range's number?

Comment: GMP: https://gmplib.org/ You want to look for the term "arbitrary precision", and you'll find heaps of information, even here or [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568446/the-best-cross-platform-portable-arbitrary-precision-math-library).

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I was solving a programming problem, and I need to store the value and do some calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No integer type defined by the C++ Standard can hold 10<sup>31</sup>. You need either

- a 128-bit integer (range 1.7 × 10<sup>38</sup>). You have to resort to compiler-specific functionality for this (e.g. `__int128_t` in Clang and GCC).
- or an arbitrary-precision integer class from a third-party library (checkout [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)).

Comment: Can I do it on java?

Comment: Java doesn't have 128-bit primitive integers even as an extension so you have to use the arbitrary-precision integer class named `BigInteger`.

Comment: @Sudarshan: why did you tag your question C++ if you want a Java solution ?

Comment: @Paul R : Basically, I was solving a problem in Google code jam. I was solving that problem with C++. But I could solve that with Java as well. If I could store the number in java, I could solve that with java. As I was trying with C++ I tagged my question with C++.

Answer (score 0):

No fundamental type integer type is guaranteed to hold that large a range.  You can find the limits in [climits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).  They're expressed as powers of 2, but it's easy to convert, 2^n is about 10^n/3.3, so `long long` will get you as far as 10^19 or so.

No floating point type can hold that range of values with whole number precision (they're too small).

You could make your own class with 14 bytes of precision (use 2 `long long` variables) which supports arithmetic operations, and internally manages arithmetic carry between the two variables.

The only alternative is to find a library which supports long, or infinite, precision.

Comment: @Sudarshan: what do you mean? If you encapsulate them in a class which overloads appropriately the arithmetic operators using it becomes almost completely transparent.